# Ubuntu Server 22.04: connecting to a different router on home network doesn't allow IP assignment

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, internet, nginx

My home network runs on 2 routers, with one upstream to the other. Recently I had to move my server to an ethernet port away from the one it was set up on, downstream to a different router. Said server won't get assigned an IP on its local network despite trying different cables to test for functionality and rebooting the router. Other devices work with the cable except for the server.

Information:

- OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS x86_64
- Kernel: 5.15.0-50-generic
- Shell: bash 5.1.16

I'm running several docker containers through portainer in it with nginx (proxy manager), but I imagine those won't be able to modify the IP configuration on the ubuntu server to any significant manner other than creating its own networks behind the host network. I'm probably wrong, as my level of understanding is still low level. Any requests for further information will be answered as well as possible.

Is this an issue with ubuntu server in general? Why is the host suddenly unable to obtain an IP address? I will test reconnecting it to the upstream router soon, so I'll update after.

UPDATE: shutting the server down, reconnecting to the upstream router, and turning it on did nothing. This is likely something to do with the server itself. Any ideas?

UPDATE: To anyone coming after, `lshw -C network` showed `*-network DISABLED` for the ethernet interface. `ip link set enp7s0 up` set it to up, but did not fix it after reboot nor did it actually allow an IP to be assigned. I ended up just reinstalling Ubuntu Server.

Comment: Ideas: Logs, `ip a`, networking settings.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, and `ip a` presented `enp7s0` as down, and checking I was able to google my way to looking up network settings, and found that through `lshw -C network` ethernet was `*-network DISABLED` for the ethernet interface, and arrived at similar questions where people believed upgrading packages messed it up. I tried `ip link set enp7s0 up` to no avail. My solution ended up just reinstalling the server and it is functional again, though this isn't much of a solution